# A subgroup of $S_n$ contains only even permutations or half of them are even.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Show that for every subgroup $H$ of $S_n$ for $n \geq 2$, either all the permutations in $H$ are even or exactly half of them are even.

Comment: I changed the title of the question as the new title is more suitable to your question.

Comment: Consider the alternating group $A_n$, now what does that tell you?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is given in the following website:
 http://users.humboldt.edu/pgoetz/Homework%20Solutions/343/hw5solns.pdf

Please find it.